# Is android:animateLayoutChanges supposed to work when a child view's height is updated?

Tags: android, android-animation

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

```
<LinearLayout
  animateLayoutChanges="true">
     <View1/> 
     <View2/>
     <View3/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let's say `View2`'s height increases at runtime. I would expect `View3` to animate downward. Instead, it snaps directly into its new position.

Why does my desired animation not occur?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html

`By default, all transition types except CHANGING are enabled.`

So if you want to animate when a child changes its size. You can do so by

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
parentView.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition);
```

Comment: Why not just `parentView.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);`?

Comment: @arekolek ViewGroup getLayoutTransition() returns null by default. Its not null only when in setLayoutTransition() is called explicitly or you set  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in xml.